# Impossible to double an integer by moving a the initial digit to last

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, decimal-expansion

[Link to the other post about this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2652233/how-one-should-approach-a-problem-involving-alteration-in-digits-of-integers)

*Prove that there does not exist an integer which is doubled when the initial digit is transferred to the end.*

So today I started working on this fairly nice-seeming problem. I think I have a solution but I only slept for 5 hours and it might be w*ck, since it has made me think that the question might not be very accurate (in a sense). Before I proceed, I know there's another post about this very same problem but I am providing potentially a different solution and trying to discuss whether the problem is accurate, so I hope this post isn't closed as a duplicate.

$Solution.$ Here's another attempt at finding a solution.

Let such integer be $z=10^na_n+10^{n-1}a_{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$ (decimal representation) then the integer $\tilde{z}=10^na_{n-1}+10^{n-1}a_{n-2}+\cdots+10a_0+a_n$ is obtained by moving the initial digit of $z$ to the last.

Now observe the following,

$$10z+a_n = 10^{n+1}a_n+10^{n}a_{n-1}+\cdots+10a_0+a_n$$
$$=10^{n+1}a_n+\tilde{z}=10^{n+1}a_n+2z$$

and so,

$$10(10^n-1)a_n=8z$$

and we can see that this is false since $8\not|10$ and $8\not|(10^n-1)$

**At this point I ask if I made any stupid mistakes, please let me know**
One comment about this problem is that the integer $0$ satisfies the condition, where taking the initial digit to the last (which happens to be the same) doubles the integer? If so, should the question be modified?

Comment: Yes, just to be watertight, the question should be modified to specify a strictly positive integer.

Comment: I suppose the question is implicitly talking about *positive* integers.

Comment: The part "which implies $a_{n−1}−a_n=a_n,a_{n−2}−a_{n−1}=a_{n−1},…a_0−a_1=a_1,a_n−a_0=a_0$" is incorrect. You are using the uniqueness of the decimal representation but this is unique only if the digits are $0-9$ your "digits" here are $-9$ to $9$

Comment: Your $a_n-a_1$ should be $a_n-a_0$. A bigger problem is that $\sum b_k10^k=\sum c_k10^k$ doesn't imply $b_k=c_k$. You are overlooking that some of those $a_k-a_{k+1}$ could be negative.

Comment: To make this more clear, note that $2*10+(-1)*1=1*10+9*(1)$ but this does not mean that $2=1$ and $-1=9$.

Comment: Also, you should link to the other post where this question is discussed.

Comment: Oh you're right! I will post the link here and I will hopefully update the solution tomorrow. Thank you @GerryMyerson and N. S.

Comment: The question in the link proposes the same problem, but doesn't give a solution.

Comment: @achillehui I didn't see your solution when I was working on this problem, but I see a lot of similarities between mine and yours. I really like the solution and if you post it as a solution, I will accept it!

Comment: What happens if you try this proof for the possibility of doubling a number by moving the last digit to the beginning?  Instead of getting an impossible condition you should get a possible one, to wit $19|(10^n-1)$ admitting an 18-digit minimal solution.  Does this check on your method work?

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi Probably. I say this because right after this problem I worked on another problem that asked to move the last digit (which in this case was given to be 6) to the front so as to quadruple the integer. I solved the problem using a similar strategy that reduced to finding $n$ such that $13|(10^{n}-1)$. I found an integer solution which was $153846$

Comment: Curiously if you had been given $4$ as the last digit the minimal solution for your second problem would have come from the repeating block for $1/39$ rather than $1/13$.  Try it!

Comment: @OscarLanzi If I have guessed what a repeating block means correctly, I think you're right since I took out the common factor of 39 and 6 to end up with 13

Comment: of course 0 would be a solution :-)